# Apps and Integrations in Account Settings

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am not seeing Apps and Integrations in my account settings.  Is this something that does not come standard that I have to purchase?

Comment: Not sure what you talkin about. Once you are logged in to https://developer.autodesk.com, use the dropdown menu under your name (upper-right) then go to "My Apps", alternatively use direct link: https://developer.autodesk.com/myapps. There you can control your keys and what API each app gets access to. That's all you can get at the moment ...

Comment: I think he is referring to BIM 360 API Apps and Integrations. If you are an ADN developer, please follow this process to request your access to the BIM 360 API. https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/bim-360-enterprise-activating-api-access-to-docs/